# Can't make SSIS regex (regular expression) work (Premium derived column component from kingswaysoft)

Tags: regex, ssis, derived-column

I'm using SSIS Productivity Pack and have encountered an issue with Premium derived column component on regex function:

```
RegexFindMatch( [my_column], [^\s]+(?="$), 1)
```

[I need to get `smth3` from string `smth1, smth2, smth3.` or `smth2, smth3.` or `, smth3` - have 3 option for input string]

I'm getting the error message

```
System.Exception: Invalid Expression: Syntax error, expected: Number, String, true, false, -, !, ~, *, (, #, ColumnWithBrackets, Name, @, NULL (SSIS Productivity Pack, v10.0.0.3034 - devenv, v15.9.28307.905)"
```

I've tried all the options I could imagine - embrace it in `()`, `""`, `[]`, preceed it with `@` and nothing does the job.

Comment: It looks like `\S+(?=\.?")` would match the 3 options.

Comment: Start with something simple, like `RegexFindMatch( [my_column], '[^,]+$', 1)` and if it does not work, the problem might be with the code. Where can we find the relevant documentation?